# MVC RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a weird issue where after calling RedirectToAction in an ActionResult function,  the code continues to execute and in the end returns me to the Edit view

I make a post back to the below Edit Function.  I have checked that the ModelState is Valid AND i get to the RedirectToAction  with no problems.   The issue i have is after hitting the RedirectToAction it continues down the code and eventually hits my return View(Airline).

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Airline Airline)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Businesses.Attach(Airline);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Airline, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Airline.Id });
        }


        return View(Airline);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return an `ActionResult` from the action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Airline.Id });
```

in your case you always return a `ViewResult`.

Comment: you beat me to it.  I just saw that!  Not sure how that got removed

Answer (score 4):

You need to return `RedirectToAction` as the result of the method, not just call it like a function.

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Airline.Id });
```